# Complex Rails has_many relationship with friendship connections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building an application which has `users` that are connected to each other through a `partnerships` table. The partnership table has `user_id` and `partner_id` columns.

`user.rb`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :partnerships
  has_many :partners, through: :partnerships
end
```

`partnership.rb`:

```
class Partnership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :partner, class_name: "User"
end
```

What I would like to happen is get all partnerships for a user, regardless of whether they are the `user_id` or `partner_id` part of the `Partnership` model.

For example, if user A adds user B, user A is the user and user B is the partner. I would like to be able to then call `@user.partnerships` on either model and get the same partnership.

How can I implement a has_many association on the `User` model that will retrieve all partnerships where the user's ID is either in the `user_id` or `partner_id` column.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use a [conditional association](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord%3a%3aAssociations%3a%3aClassMethods-label-Customizing+the+query):

```
has_many :partnerships, ->(user) { where("user_id = ? OR partner_id = ?", user.id, user.id) }
```

Comment: you should use "amisted" gem for friendship management. please look at [https://github.com/raw1z/amistad/wiki]